# Sound buttons not working after upgrading to GNOME 3.16

Tags: gnome, 15.04, xps

I upgraded GNOME to latest version, then I downgraded it.

Sound buttons stop working. I tried to apply :

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up
'XF86AudioRaiseVolume'
```

But no way, the buttons still not working.

Comment: What is the current GNOME version?

Comment: Use `gnome-session --version` to check.

Comment: GNOME Shell 3.14.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by re-setting sound shortcuts from :
System settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Sound and Media

Answer (score 0):

Install GNOME 3.16 again, and yes, I'am sure

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

Upgrade your system again, and yes, I'm sure **;)**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now remove GNOME 3.16 in a clean way

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

---

If this not work, backup and reset your GNOME 3 configuration

```
cd ~
mkdir ./.old-gnome-config/ && \
    mv ./.gnome* ./.old-gnome-config/ && \
    mv .gconf* ./.old-gnome-config/ && \
    mv ./.cache ./.old-gnome-config/ && \
    mv ./.dbus ./.old-gnome-config/ && \
    mv ./.dmrc ./.old-gnome-config/ && \
    mv ./.mission-control ./.old-gnome-config/ && \
    mv ~/.config/dconf/* ./.old-gnome-config/
```

<sup>Partially taken from [here](http://www.faqoverflow.com/askubuntu/56313.html)</sup>

Log-out and log-in. The backup is in `~/.old-gnome-config`

Comment: Not found error :
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/ vivid/main gjs amd64 1.43.3-0ubuntu1~vivid1
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gjs/libgjs0e_1.43.3-0ubuntu1~vivid1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gjs/gjs_1.43.3-0ubuntu1~vivid1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

Comment: @Nasreddine Check your network, the servers are up and running.

Comment: I've tried your solution, not changes. Buttons still not working; while others work correctly.

Comment: Please create another user and login with this user. After that check it again.

Comment: It works correctly in the new user account. It's a question of config I think, how restore default settings to get buttons working ?

Comment: @Nasreddine Updated my answer. And sorry for my rude words some days ago. :\

Comment: I've removed old configs, no effect !!

Comment: That's bad. It's something with your user configuration. But I have no more ideas... Does it works after a re-login?

Comment: I've even restarted the computer!

Comment: Rename the `.config` folder to force the creation of a new one. Re-login . If that not work, rename all `.` folders. If your buttons work after that, copy the content of the folders back, step by step.

Comment: I know, it's a brute force attack, but the problem is in the configuration of your user

Comment: Which `.` files do you have in your home folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26231/discussion-between-nasreddine-and-a-b).