# Multimedia keys (previous, play/pause, next) don't work

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, multimedia, keys

Only those three keys won't work. Volume, screen brightness keys are working like a charm. Anyone know what's the problem? I tried already manualy to adjust media shortcuts eventho I knew it's system adjusted, so I opened up System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Sound & Media but everthing is ok there...

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on my HP 250 G4 Notebook, standard keyboard with numeric keys.

Comment: we need to know the make and model of either the keyboard or the computer, preferably both

Comment: Start `xev` and check if there is a output for the keys

Comment: mchid Sorry,  I've edited my question.   @A.B.  I did it and this is what i get for my play key:  " KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0xd4, subw 0x4600002, time 3494403, (65,56), root:(935,222),
    state 0x10, keycode 172 (keysym 0x1008ff14, XF86AudioPlay), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False "

Comment: What? What's working? :)

Comment: @A.B. play/pause, next, previous multimedia keys

Comment: Write an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sound buttons not working after upgrading to GNOME 3.16](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632991/sound-buttons-not-working-after-upgrading-to-gnome-3-16)

Answer (score -1):

Typing `xev` in the terminal solved my problem, play/pause, next, previous multimedia keys are working now.

Comment: I'm afraid you've got something misunderstood. `xev` shows only some information about the keys and mouse events. The program lets keys not suddenly working.